# Should this question about cockpit painting colors be reopened as not a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, moderation, exact-duplicates

So, I saw that [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/83367/why-is-the-cockpit-color-of-eastern-aircrafts-different-than-westerns?noredirect=1#comment221991_83367) was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16434/why-are-russian-cockpit-panels-painted-in-turquoise), but I don't think it should be. The second question is "why are the cockpits of Soviet aircraft painted blue-green", while the first question (the one closed as a duplicate) was "why are the cockpits of Soviet and Western aircraft painted different colors". The answers for them should be different, since the answer for the first question should address why, if the Soviets found that blue-green was objectively the best color to paint aircraft, the didn't West copy them.

I don't have the reputation to vote to reopen, and one of the diamond moderators has told me to open a thread on Meta about it after I left a comment and a moderator flag asking to reopen it.

Comment: One thing that's really helpful is to edit the question to make it more clear why it's not a duplicate, as people reviewing whether it should be reopened may not read all relevant comments or meta posts.

Answer (score 1):

They may be worded very slightly differently, but the answer(s) given on the older question quite demonstrably answers the more recent as best we're able. ie, if you're asking about the *motivation* only the decision maker them self could answer that,

I fail to see how they are different questions. If the community decide I am wrong and cast reopen votes, I of course will not intervene.

Disclosure: I closed this particular one as a duplicate.

Comment: The answers for the older one don't answer the newer one at all, though? A suitable answer for the older one is "because the Soviets found turquoise to be the best color to paint cockpits", while an answer for the newer one would be "Soviets found that turquoise is the best color to paint cockpits, but the West didn't adopt this as a standard because..."

Comment: @nick012000 Im still not convinced. The newer one says "Why are western and eastern cockpits different colors" and the older answer is "Because the soviets decided they liked turquioise". AS I said, we almost certainly cannot summise why the west didnt agree. If you can find some source that I'm wrong then maybe it might be answerable.

Comment: "AS I said, we almost certainly cannot summise why the west didnt agree." I disagree. There are almost definitely records *somewhere* in the FAA's archives for meetings held regarding standards on this topic, and there may well be US Military documents on the topic as well, though those might be secret. I don't know where, but they're almost definitely there.

Comment: @nick012000 OK, well lets wait for some other opinion, and some reopen votes and i'll look forward to reading the proposed answer.